# How to make the sprite move positions when the screen is tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

I would like my sprite to move from one side of the screen to the other like this:

Before tapped:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqF76.jpg

And then after the screen has been tapped:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dytrg.jpg

Would it start with something like this:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if you want to get the position of your finger when you touch the screen and apply to the sprite's position or just to change the position of the sprite when you touch the screen.

If you want to get your finger's position inside touchesBegan and apply that position to the sprite:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
        spriteNode.position = location;
    }
}
```

If you want to just change the sprite's position to the opposite side of the tree every time you touch:

First you need to keep track of which side your sprite is currently. Let's create a BOOL to hold that info:

```
BOOL isRightSide;
```

Then, at the beginning, if your sprite start at the right side of the tree, just assign TRUE to the boolean.

Finally, in the touch event:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (isRightSide) {
        //Change to sprite's position to the LEFT side 
    } else {
        //Change to sprite's position to the RIGHT side 
    }

    isRightSide = !isRightSide;
}
```

I hope this helps =)

Comment: When I click inside the app it closes, do you happen to know why? Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the exception message at the output box?